# Updating records with image in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

This code works when Updating data with image. However, The problem is when i edit the record that is existing and i do not change the image. The `picturebox` becomes null.

```
 Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspUpdate", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studID", frmView.dgv1.SelectedCells(0).Value)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StudPic", SqlDbType.Image))
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Name) AndAlso System.IO.File.Exists(a.FileName)) Then
            cmd.Parameters("@StudPic").Value = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SurName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtStudLN.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtStudFN.Text
   Else

    cmd.Parameters("@StudPic").Value = DBNull.Value 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SurName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtStudLN.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtStudFN.Text
Endif
```

Code when choosing an image in `Picture box`

```
  Private Sub PictureBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.DoubleClick
        Dim picl As String
        a.Filter = Nothing
        picl = a.FileName
        a.ShowDialog()
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(a.FileName)
    End Sub
```

BEGIN TRAN

Code for update

```
UPDATE p 
            SET p.father_firstname = @FFirstName, 
                p.father_lastname = @FLastName, 
                p.Father_MI = @FMI,
                p.Father_Occupation = @FOccupation, 
                p.Father_TelNUm = @FTelNum ,
                p.Mother_FirstName = @MFirstName, 
                p.Mother_LastName = @MLastName, 
                p.Mother_MI = @MMI,
                p.Mother_Occupation = @MOccupation, 
                p.Mother_TelNum = @MTelNum,
                p.Contact_FirstName = @CFirstName ,
                p.Contact_LastName = @CLastName,
                p.Contact_MI = @CMI, 
                p.Contact_Mobile = @CMobile, 
                p.Contact_TelNum = @CTelNum 
                FROM parentinformation p 
                INNER JOIN studentinformation s 
                ON p.parentid = s.parentid 
                WHERE s.StudentID = @studID;
                UPDATE StudentInformation 
                SET Surname = @SurName,
                FirstName = @FirstName,
                MiddleName = @middleName,
                StudAddress =@StudAddress,
                BirthDay = @Birthday, 
                Gender = @Gender, 
                Nationality = @Nationality,
                BirthPlace = @BirthPlace, 
                TelNum = @TelNum, 
                SchoolWhereGraduated = @SWG,
                DatesWhenGraduated = @DWG, 
                SchoolLastAttended = @SLA,
                Note = @Note,
                StudImage = @StudPic        
                where StudentID = @studID

        COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: What System.IO.File.Exists(a.FileName) returns?

Comment: Could you post the actual command you are executing? If you do not need to update the image why is it being passed as a parameter..

Comment: @ehh i already Edit the post above for clearer explanation

Comment: @vmachan i already Edit the post above for clearer explanation

Comment: It seems you are executing a stored procedure called dbo.uspUpdate, if that is correct, I think you should change that so if the image parameter is passed it updates the image in the record or else does not.

Comment: @vmachan , Yes i executing it with a stored procedure. Can you help me to that with my existing code?

Comment: I would need to see the code, so if you post it I can try and help

Comment: @vmachan , i already post the update code of my store procedure, Anyway, can i manipulate it in vb.net instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SQL you can change the following line

```
 StudImage = @StudPic
```

TO

```
 StudImage = ISNULL(@StudPic, StudImage)
```

This will check of the passed parameter @StudPic is NULL and if so will just update the image with it's current value.

You need to default the @StudPic parameter value to NULL when you do not pass it from VB.Net. This [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189330(v=sql.105).aspx) tells you how to set defaults for stored procedure parameters.

Comment: Thanks It works, but one thing i would like to ask.. If i click the cancel button on choosing image. This gives me an error. [Path is not of a legal form](http://img6.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/21912/219127062576fc358c8e615b908527e2e41be90e.png) How can i handle this error?

Comment: FileName is not correct check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739756/argument-exception-the-path-is-not-of-a-legal-form-vb-net